# laravel quer strings are not available in request->query() result

Tags: laravel

im working on laravel 5.3, i wants to send page numbers as a query params to my api. 
url is correct and its like that xyz.com/rewards?page=2
but when i debug $request->query() in controller i return results `{"url":"api\/rewards"}`
im working on production and facing this issue on production. 
on the other side when i run code in local server and request to api with same url, it works fine and i receive `page = 2`  as a query params in $request object.
here is my code of line to test page query strings.

```
public function index(Request $request){
      return $request->query();
    }
```

problem is that why im not able to get query strings on production server

Comment: I believe you want to be using `$request->get('query_string_variable');` rather than `$request->query()`.

Comment: i resolved, basically there was issue in my .htaccess. .htaccess was bocking my query strings..